# AngularJS - controller and factory - where am I going wrong?

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and cannot pinpoint where I am going wrong. I'm just trying to simply inject my factory into my controller, reference said controller within my html and use ng-repeat to present the data. I can't even get it to work solely using the handlebars and excluding ng-repeat. I'm here to see if there is just something glaringly wrong with my code that I'm missing. I've been going through two separate tutorials to get a hang on this and was sure I had it. I guess not though.

HTML:

```
<html data-ng-app='theApp'>

<div class='sideRow' data-ng-controller='mainTagController'>

<div class='sideRowLabel'>TAGS</div>

<div class='sideRowData'>

<a href='page.html' class='blueLink' data-ng-repeat='mainTag in mainTags'>{{ mainTag }}</a>

</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
/// <reference path="../../vendor/angular.min.js" />

var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);

theApp.factory('mainTagFactory', function() { 

    var mainTags = [ 

        { mainTag: 'Tag 1'},
        { mainTag: 'Tag 2'},
        { mainTag: 'Tag 3'},

    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getMainTags = function() { 

        return mainTags 

    }

    return factory 

});

theApp.controller('mainTagController', function ($scope, mainTagFactory) {

    init(); 

    function init() {

        $scope.mainTags = mainTagFactory.getMainTags(); 

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you were just missing some semicolons inside the factory function.

Here you can find a working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ME49s/

```
factory.getMainTags = function() { 

    return mainTags 

}

return factory
```

I also felt free to replace {{ mainTag }} with {{ mainTag.mainTag }}, as I thought this is what you wanted to achieve.

Hope it works for you

Pietro

Answer (score -1):

```
var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);

theApp.factory('mainTagFactory', function() { 

    var mainTags = [ 

        { mainTag: 'Tag 1'},
        { mainTag: 'Tag 2'},
        { mainTag: 'Tag 3'},

    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getMainTags = function() { 

        return mainTags 

    }

    return factory 

});

theApp.controller('mainTagController', ['$scope', 'mainTagFactory',  function ($scope, mainTagFactory) {

    init(); 

    function init() {

        $scope.mainTags = mainTagFactory.getMainTags(); 

    }

}]);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out how you updated the OP's code, as it is hard from inspection to tell how this differs from the JS code block they posted.